# A 'Commit' Task In The Performance Inspector Is Slowing Down My JavaScript Game

Tags: javascript, css, web-performance

This is probably relatively simple, but unfortunatly it's not an easy thing to google.

A client has tasked me with making a little 404 page runner game, similar to the google dino game. It runs fairly well despite using a ton of css animation.

My big problem right now: every once in a while there is a 'Commit' task called that lags the game for a second. It's sometimes enough to make the player lose.

[Commit event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgwdp.png)

All I can tell is that it might be something to do with rendering the CSS. But google has turned up empty.

I would apreciate any tips on how to minimize the effects of whatever this is. Thank you!

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what this "Commit" task was referring to? Running into this issue myself currently :(

Comment: Commit, or compositor commit is a step in Chrome's rendering pipeline. More info here: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/blinkng/

Comment: Have you fixed this Issue ? If yes, Can you share what all things you done in order to fix this issue? I'm currenly facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could inspect your code keeping 'The pixel pipeline' in mind -> https://web.dev/rendering-performance/

When animating on the web you want to keep the pipeline as short as possible.

For example: if you want to animate an element moving from left to right you could animate the `left` value but this will cause a layout recalculation followed by paint and composite. You could do the same thing by using `transform: translateX()`, this will only cause a composite recalculation which is much shorter.

Maybe these articles also help:

- https://web.dev/animations-overview/
- https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a
- https://web.dev/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing/

Answer (score 0):

I had Commit tasks taking up to 5 seconds. The problem went away when I disabled "Enable advanced paint instrumentation (slow)".

[image]